# How to test a product of a OLS estimators?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, nonlinear

I estimated a vector $\beta $ using OLS $\hat \beta =(\hat e_1  \hat e_2  \hat e_3)$ and I have the covariance matrice $\hat v(\hat \beta )$.

How can I test this null hypothesis $H_0 : \hat e_1  \hat e_2=0$ ??

Comment: Presumably $\hat\beta$ is estimating parameters $(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ and you wish to test the hypothesis $\beta_1\beta_2=0.$  (You can't hypothesize about the product of *estimates:* hypotheses are about *parameters.*)  But that's equivalent to $\beta_1=0$ or $\beta_2=0,$ both of which are tested in standard software output.